# How to make Entity Framework use a web service for all accesses to an SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Due to some regulations in the organization we're creating a web application for, we can't have the credentials for accessing the database. All access to the database is done through a service accepting SQL queries, stored procedure names, etc. The service has a simple web interface where an authorized user enters the credentials for connecting to the database, and starts the service.

We have created and know the structure of the database completely and have the complete EF code-first models for it. I would like to use EF in our data-access repository classes. My research on the issue leads me to implementing a custom data provider for EF. But I thought we might be able to hook up somewhere in the `SqlClient` provider where the queries are actually sent to the database, and send them to the service instead.

Is that possible? or is the idea feasible at all?

Comment: EF would exist inside your web service, not in the consumer.

Comment: The web service has no business logic. only runs the SQL on DB. And 'I would like to use EF in our data-access repository classes.'

Comment: I would recommend against using EF in this situation then. In fact, why do you need a web service to avoid getting the SQL credentials? Why not just push the web app to a production system that you don't have access to, let the dev-ops team manage it entirely.

Comment: Actually we are all the dev team and we have written the web service ourselves, which can't be changed. Unwieldy regulations, you know.

Comment: So you are restricting yourself from getting the passwords? :)

Comment: Exactly :D We actually have the passwords but there is some supervisor who would check our codes e.g. not having a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the EF is the best way, it depends on the Service that access database. Anyway, if you need to consume that service you need to write an EF provider that access to "Your Sql Client" (and not SqlClient) and write "Your Sql Client".

About rewrite the EF Provider, if you start from SQL Server provider it's not really hard because you can just rewrite the part that loads the SqlClient (actually I don't remember but it could be that is few lines of code to change) and eventually delete DDL and DB First code.

About write "Your Sql Client" you can start from
https://jetentityframeworkprovider.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

In that code, forget about EF implementation, you can just use JetConnectionFactory, JetConnection, JetCommand, JetDataReader and JetTransaction. They are just wrapper like you need.

Comment: I took a look at the MS Access EF provider code, but, for my case, I'm not quite sure how should I use the existing `SqlClient` classes. Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the required wrappers? Isn't the `JetProviderServices` class the main entry point for the thing?

Comment: Sorry, probably I was not clear. The SQL Client is the part you can't use at all. You need to write "your own connection client" based on the wrappers. This is the work. You also need to write an EF Provider but in that case you can use the SQL Server EF Provider (so you can use the query generator). The only part that you need to change of EF provider is the part where the EF provider use the SQL Client. You have to change that part and make the EF provider to use "your own connection client". Probably is very few lines of code.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get exactly what type of classes I need to implement. Do you know of a link where these inner workings are explained?

Comment: You could start downloading Entity Framework source code. In EF Sql Server provider you can replace System.Data.SqlClient with MyCompanyClient. After that you need to search where the SqlClient.* was instantiated (probably few places) and istantiate MyCompanyClient.*. Actually I can't remember but is a factory so it could be that the instance is create not with new. The classes that you need to rewrite are SqlClient classes. You can find samples in JetConnectionFactory, JetConnection, JetCommand, JetDataReader and JetTransaction